# Is it possible to store ImageSpan in Room database?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-glide, imagespan

I have a **recyclerView** where I need to list emojis from URL and for this, I have implemented a Glide mechanism to get a bitmap from URL and then ImageSpan to load it in **TextView**.

There is some white space for the first time but once it loaded everything works perfectly. To overcome this issue, I need to store **ImageSpan** to somewhere so that Image loading time can be minimized.

Comment: Can't you use UNICODE for the emoji? Apart from that saving `ImageSpan` in database is not possible. Since u are using Glide so it will cache the image once its loaded . So you can make `ImageSpan` each time. For that you need save metaData (Text + URL) in the database.

Comment: I am implementing Joypixel (https://www.joypixels.com/) emoji to replace default UNICODE and Yeah, I have done exactly what you said but the time to fetch the image from the server is slow most of the time and it is causing lag while scrolling.

Comment: Well if that's the case, to make it more convenient you can create a Custom TextView and handle All the spanning part there . Also use a placeholder for loading emoji and enable the cache in glide . So that next time it will use local cache for image .